# Error code: 0x80004005. error code 0xC020907B.error code 0xC0209029. error code 0xC02020C4. SSIS

Tags: ssis, error-code

Hi I am trying to execute an Initial Load package With CDC start and end tasks and I am getting the following error messages when I execute the Initial Load package in SSIS. Can you help me figure these out?

[OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FactSalesID', table 'DemoDW.dbo.Staging_Fact_Sales'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".

[OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[OLE DB Source [38]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Note:

I made sure the identity is set to Yes with an increment of 1 on the destination table. The datatypes are all match (int) and and the Allow Null box is unchecked. They Null box cannot be changed sine they have Primary Keys set to them. I am running SSDT as administrator and it is the 2017 version

SSDT : 15.1.62002.01090

Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 15.0.2000.128

Please assist thanks.

Comment: Do not map to an identity column, just allow the default to happen.